# I just want to the connection to be closed when the request of HTTP/1.1 is over

Tags: c++, http

Now I write a C++ program  to get every page with  certain URLs(Just like a Spider program of Search Engine),so send this :"`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.163.com\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n`" to the host,but when I recv() all the packages from the host,The connection was not closed immediately. So What can I do now with HTTP/1.1?
I use the epoll the check the sockets when there is a READ event.

```
void* NetService::epoll_process ( void* arg )
{
    NetService* netservice = ( NetService* ) arg;
    int nfds;
    int sockfd;

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        // return the nums of sockfds which there can be read or write now.
        nfds=epoll_wait ( netservice->epollfd,netservice->events,20,200 );

        //process the active sockfds
        for ( int i=0; i < nfds; ++i )
        {

            if ( netservice->events[i].events&EPOLLIN )
            {
                if ( ( sockfd = netservice->events[i].data.fd ) < 0 )
                    continue;
                netservice->recv_pkg ( sockfd );
            }

        }
        /*there should to check all the sockfds of their timeouts;*/
        if ( nfds == 0 )
        {
            //cout<<"**********time out***********"<<endl;

        }
    } //(for(;;))

    close ( netservice->epollfd );

    return NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize the `Connection: Close` header.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an *existing HTTP client library* like e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Why do you want to code your own HTTP client library? (because **HTTP is not that simple** even when restricted to `GET` requests)

(And it is the client side, that is your side, who should close the connection)

And Curl's site lists several [competitors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html) (i.e. alternative libraries)

Comment: Thanks , I have tried the curl before, and it may be more complex for me(I just need to the operation of GET), It takes some time to initial its easy_handle and other things.Now I write it myself, and it can go faster  when there are many connections at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What means that the connection was not closed immediately? recv is not returning 0? I think you have a problem in your code, can you post the code? I've tested www.163.com, using telnet, and connection was closed immediately.

Comment: Thank you,I just send() the char* to the host, and my epoll also can recv() all the response from the host, but it can not be closed immediately(I can recv 0 a few seconds later),So I think there someting wrong happened in my "HTTP" protocal  code,and I used to read the RESPONSE head,and pick out the Content-Lenght field,but it failed because some web page without that field,

Comment: are you using `EPOLLET` flag? If you are using this flag without `EPOLLONESHOT`, do you read the socket until no data is available?